# Stepwise Regression in R Studio - Using Alpha value instead of AIC?

Tags: r

I want to run a forward, backward, and stepwise procedure on my data. However, I would like to set the alpha value to 0.05. I know that R uses AIC and that corresponds to an alpha of approx 0.15.

I know I can run this code:
'''
step(model2, direction = 'backward')
'''

However, that uses AIC. Is there a way to specify that I want the alpha value to = 0.05? 
Or is there a different line of code that I run instead to ensure an alpha of 0.05?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Significance Controlled Variable Selection in Linear Regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SignifReg/SignifReg.pdf)
 - specifically the `SignifReg` function.

> Significance controlled variable selection selects variables in a linear regression model with different directions of the algorithm (forward, backward, stepwise) based on a chosen criterion (AIC,
>   BIC, adjusted r-square, PRESS or p-value). The algorithm selects a final model with only significant
>   variables based on a correction choice of False Discovery Rate, Bonferroni, or fixed level.